sequelize getter in HasMany error TypeError: is not a function
I want to make a getter beetween two table. In the controler of one who get in the other, the getter is not a function.
The model Comitee who as many club
export class Comitee extends Model<InferAttributes<Comitee>, InferCreationAttributes<Comitee>>  {
    ...

     @HasMany(() => Club, {
        foreignKey: {
          name: 'comiteeId',
        }})
    declare Club?: NonAttribute<Club[]>
    declare getClubs: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<Club>
}

The controler Comitee
export const getComitees = async (_: Request, res: Response) => {
  const comitees = await Comitee.findAll();
  const comiteesToHash =  comitees.map(  async (comitee) => {
    const idComitee = comitee.id
        const comiteeClub = await Comitee.findByPk(idComitee)
    console.log("clubs", comiteeClub?.getClubs)
        //TypeError: comiteeClub.getClubs is not a function
    return  (
              []
            )})
};

But the getClub is not a function and i do not know why ?
Thanks
i follow this : https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/associations/has-many/
************* edit *****************
I modifie a little the code :
import { Sequelize,Model, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes, NonAttribute,CreationOptional, DataTypes, HasManyGetAssociationsMixin} from '@sequelize/core'
import { Attribute, PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull, BelongsTo, BelongsToMany, HasOne, HasMany } from '@sequelize/core/decorators-legacy'


import { Club } from './Club';

export class Comitee extends Model<InferAttributes<Comitee>, InferCreationAttributes<Comitee>>  {
    @Attribute(DataTypes.INTEGER)
    @PrimaryKey
    @AutoIncrement
    declare id: CreationOptional<number>

    @HasMany(() => Club, 'comiteeId')
    declare clubs?: NonAttribute<Club[]>
    declare getClubs: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<Club>
}

export const GET = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse ) => {


    const comitee = await Comitee.findByPk(1)
    if (!comitee) return NextResponse.json(" pas de comité trouvée")
    console.log("comitee", comitee)
    // this return the good value
    
    console.log("comitee get clubs", await comitee.getClubs())
    // this retun getClubs() is not a function
  } 
}


But still the same error.
I do not understand. I make a good link beetween the table and with the "getClubs" in model the type
declare getClubs: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<Club>

The type say it is a function
What i did bad ?
Sorry to my english and thanks
